# Delphi, FireMonkey and PostgreSQL

Tags: delphi, postgresql, firemonkey

I was reading the Embarcadero FireMonkey literature and it lists a lot of db platforms, but not PostgreSQL. Is there a way to build a cross-platform PostgreSQL Delphi application?

Comment: I am not aware of a cross-platform-ready PostgreSQL driver for Delphi.

Comment: UniDAC supports PostgreSQL - see http://www.devart.com/pgdac/

Comment: And UniDAC compiles and runs on a Mac? Their website says it does, mjn you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi XE2 includes the dbExpress ODBC driver which can be used with  the PostgreSQL ODBC driver for access this database. Unfortunally the `dbExpress ODBC driver` only supports windows (for now).

For cross-platform development you can try the [PgDAC](http://www.devart.com/pgdac/overview.html) component from [DevArt](http://www.devart.com)

> PgDAC is a cross-platform solution for developing applications using
>   various IDEs: RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder, Lazarus (and FPC) on
>   Windows, Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, and FreeBSD for both x86 and x64
>   platforms. PgDAC also provides support for the FireMonkey platform,
>   which allows you to develop visually spectacular high-performance
>   native applications for Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: ODBC is a microsoft technology, there is a such thing as "ODBC on Mac" although it's not much used. Percent chance of that being useful on a Mac in the next few years is near zip. Apparently MS Office (MS Access specifically) on Mac, does use ODBC.

Answer (score 3):

[PostgreSQL Data Access Components](http://www.devart.com/pgdac/) by DevArt:

> PgDAC is a cross-platform solution for developing applications using
>   various IDEs: RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder, Lazarus (and FPC) on
>   Windows, Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, and FreeBSD for both x86 and x64
>   platforms. PgDAC also provides support for the FireMonkey platform,
>   which allows you to develop visually spectacular high-performance
>   native applications for Windows and Mac OS X.